# Is os.Stat() enough to judge the existence of a file?

Tags: go

i have read about this code in a book.
It is about to use 'os.Stat' to judge the existence of a file.

```
func checkExistance(fileName string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsExist(err) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

and i'm wondering if this judgment "os.IsExist(err)" is necessary?
Is "os.Stat" enough to judge the existence of a file?

can i just simplify this code to

```
func checkExistance(fileName string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

this?

looking forward to valuable answers, thanks.

Comment: This is absolutely terrible code. Getting some error from `Stat` doesn’t mean you should just ignore it and assume the file doesn’t exist. (Possible history: it was originally `if !os.IsNotExist(err)` and someone incorrectly assumed that that was equivalent to `if os.IsExist(err)` – still bad either way.) Which book is it?

Comment: At least the check on non-existence could be like this `errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist)`

Comment: Most code should never check existence alone, it should just use the file or create the file if it needs. Trying to check then use a file leads to [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race conditions. So no, `os.Stat` isn't sufficient in general, because the state of the world can change before you can act on the results of `os.Stat` (not to mention your simplified code could result in other errors like a permission error rather than a lack of file)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: in the snippet you pasted, `os.IsExist(err)` is redundant because it checks for an error that cannot be returned by `os.Stat()`.

The general way to check for a file's existence in go is, as you yourself wrote in your question, to check if `os.Stat()` returns a `nil` error.

---

for reference:

The code for the standard library is documented online at https://pkg.go.dev

For example:

- the doc for the `os` package is here : https://pkg.go.dev/os
- the doc for `os.IsExist()` and `os.Stat()` is here : https://pkg.go.dev/os#IsExist and https://pkg.go.dev/os#Stat

All symbols are clickable and point to the actual code for the standard library, so you can also check the implementation online.

The doc does provide some insights for your question, but not all. For example: when reading the doc for `os.IsExist()` or the error value `fs.ErrExist`, it does not describe in what situations this error is returned.

This error can be returned in situations where you try to create a file and get a "[name] already exists" error, like creating a file with the same name as a directory, or setting the O_EXCL flag in a call to `os.OpenFile()`. `os.Stat()` does no such thing which is why it won't return this error.

Answer (score -2):

The os.Stat() func will return
`stats, err` . You can check if both are nil. If your `err` is nil, and your `stats` is not nil. the the location exists.

Comment: It is not sufficient. A file can exist even if `err` is not `nil`.